# Why does using for loop for finding prime number runs only runs once?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, primes

I want to find the prime numbers up to the given number but my loop only runs once and my output is only 2 and 3, where did I went wrong?

```
def primer_check(n):
    prime_state = True
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        if i == 2:
            print(2)
            continue
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0:
                prime_state = False
                break
        if prime_state: print(i)

n = int(input("Enter a number to see the prime numbers up to that number : "))
primer_check(n)
```

Comment: You need to reset `prime_state` for EVERY new number.  Move its initialization inside the first `for` loop.

Comment: And your check for `i == 2` is not necessary.  If `i` is 2, the loop will not run any iterations, so it will print 2 anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and think carefully about the logic of the code. This is not a debugging service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to set prime_state to True everytime when you start a new loop.here is the code.you are almost correct .Hope it helps :)

```
def primer_check(n):
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        prime_state = True
        if i == 2:
            print(2)
            continue
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0:
                prime_state = False
                break
        if prime_state: print(i)
n = int(input("Enter a number to see the prime numbers up to that number : "))
primer_check(n)
```

Comment: You DON'T need to set it before the loop starts.